# Changing active dropdown tab background color in bootstrap 3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following css to change background color of navbar dropdown active link.

```css
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open.active > a:hover, 
.navbar .nav > li.dropdown.open > a
{
   color: #fff;
   background-color: #b91773;
   border-color: #fff;
}
```

It properly change background color of active dropdown link as shown in screenshot.
[image]

But if i extend same css for nav-tabs it doesn work. here is css class

```css
.nav .nav-tabs > li.dropdown.open.active > a, 
.nav .nav-tabs > li.dropdown.open.active > a:hover
{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b91773;
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

Here is output
[image]

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think this should work:

```css
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.active.open > a, 
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.active.open > ul.dropdown-menu a:hover,
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.open > a, 
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.open > ul.dropdown-menu a:hover
{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #b91773;
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

Note no space between `.nav.nav-tabs` cause to select for having both and not the second followed by the first.

caret:

```css
.nav.nav-tabs > li.dropdown.active.open > a span.caret {border-top-color: #fff;border-bottom-color: #fff;}
```

Comment: tried it but still not working. may be updating it directly in bootstrap customization section solve this issue.

Comment: could you provide a bootply or jsfiddle showing the above not work? i thik i should work or i do not understand your question, see: http://bootply.com/83383

Comment: your bootply shows your css working fine. may be some other css classes in my project overlap it. any how thanks.

Comment: i reviewed and found my dropdown was not active therefore your css not applied. by adding two more lines in your css, it worked perfectly on both active and normal dropdown open state.

Answer (score 1):

You should fint the exact class of the dropdown menu. It could be in your nav or not. I changed the active class color of the pagination property of the Bootstrap Theme like this:

```
ul.dropdown-menu>li.active>a:hover{
    background: #419641 !important;
}

ul.dropdown-menu>li.active>a{
    background: #51AB51 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown.open a:focus {
    background-color: #6dbcc9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier if you could make a jsfiddle. if not then here is what you can do.

1- make sure that the tab Added lies exactly in ".nav .nav-tabs > li.dropdown.open.active" classes and the path is correct. IF not, it wont work.

2- So, find out if you have added a class that is not relevant or you have not added a relevant class.