# How to change the color of selected dropdown in bootstrap navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whenever a dropdown item is clicked its color changes to white that makes the white text unreadable.

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011582/changing-active-dropdown-tab-background-color-in-bootstrap-3-0) but the solution doesn't work for me. [Here](https://www.bootply.com/p1nFc476lk#) is my snippet

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Demo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Applications<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left">
                            <li><a href="#">Communications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Environmental</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Programmable</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Product Selector</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="background-color:#000;margin-top:15px; border-radius: 0">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="background-color:#000;margin-top:15px;border-radius: 0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="color:#fff;"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart logo-small"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user logo-small"></i></a>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I want the background of the active selection to be the same color as the dropdown item background. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the relevant selector. 
Change it to whichever color you need. [Updated example](https://www.bootply.com/p1nFc476lk#)

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-color: initial; /* Equivalent to background-color: transparent */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap applies focus classes. You will need to override those as well.

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  /* Your styles here. */
}
```

But you've done it with the following CSS selector, `.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover`. Add to the selector you already have (if you want the same styles for hover and focus) for `:focus`.

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.nav.navbar-nav li a:focus {
  /* Your existing styles. */
}
```

FWIW, the link to the other StackOverflow post you have is related to the Navbar, not Dropdowns.

Comment: Better not to target both `:hover` and `:focus` pseudo classes since he is only inquiring about the latter.

Comment: That's how Bootstrap applies the styles by default, with `:hover` and `:focus` paired. If you don't want to pair the styles like Bootstrap has, then yes, you could apply them separately.

Comment: But he only needs to override the `:focus` state since the `:hover` styles aren't unwanted.

Comment: There is a tiny gap between the dropdown and the navbar. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @Adrift didn't' say hover wasn't unwanted. Bye.

Comment: @TripVik `.dropdown-menu` adds a `1px` border. Remove the border. Also, your browser's Dev Tools are a great way to debug these issues. In this case, right-click the element, then select Inspect. You will see the markup of your page and some CSS on the side. This is what is being applied to the element in order of specificity.

Comment: @hungerstar Thanks!